# How to fix "Cannot locate resource" for an image

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have a wpf application that has a folder that holds all the images needed (called Images). In the Images folder I have imgAdd.png and the file path points to the correct place on my computer. The problem is, when I open the project in Visual Studio, I'm faced with multiple errors saying "Cannot locate resource 'images/imgadd.png'."

The Build Action is set to Resource, the file path is correct, I'm not sure why the picture isn't being found.

```
ImageSource="imgAdd.png"

Error   3   Cannot locate resource 'images/imgadd.png'.

<CommonControls:ccBilingualButton Canvas.Left="12" Canvas.Top="0" Cursor="Hand" Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,86,6" Name="btnAddJustPerson" TabIndex="8" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="75" LabelEnglish="Add" LabelFrench="Add" ImageSource="imgAdd.png" FontWeight="Bold" ImageLocation="Top" Foreground="Black" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" BorderBrush="DarkBlue" BorderThickness="1" />
```

Comment: It seems that the file is incorrectly set as a project Resource. Would you please post the parts from the .vbproj file that concern this image?

Comment: I've added the complete html markup for the button where this image is needed.

Comment: I mean the Project File, the file in your project directory (you won't see it in Visual Studio) that defines amongst other things which files are part of your project. For a vb.NET project it will have a .vbproj extension.